# What is OnionCat?

Tags: onioncat, ipv6, tunnel

With Tor itself, it is only possible to do TCP due to [SOCKS5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) limitations. [OnionCat](https://www.onioncat.org/) allows you to do more than TCP through Tor; how does this work?

Comment: title asks one question, then detail partially answers question and asks a second one

Answer (score 5):

OnionCat is a Tor-based decentralized peer-to-peer VPN. It acts like a single IPv6 subnet hidden inside Tor permitting a hidden service to be transformed into an IPv6 address on the subnet. In BSD land this shows up as a tun(4) device. One can do udp (dns, nfs, etc) or tcp or even IPSec between OnionCat instances (and only between OnionCat instances; not out to the clearnet).

As the [OpenBSD ports](http://ports.su/net/onioncat) tree states:

> OnionCat creates a transparent IP layer on top of Tor's hidden
>   services. It transmits any kind of IP-based data transparently through
>   the Tor network on a location hidden basis. You can think of it as a
>   point-to-multipoint VPN between hidden services.

More info can be found [here](https://www.onioncat.org/). OnionCat is not officially associated with the Tor Project.

Answer (score 3):

I try an alternative simplistic explanation.

- [You need to set up a hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en).
- Your partner needs to set up a hidden service.

OnionCat :

- connects from hidden service to hidden service.
- provides an IPv6 for you
- provides an IPv6 for your partner

Now you can use IPv6, TCP and UDP with your partner.

What is OnionCat NOT:

- A magic way to let you connect to clear-net destinations using UDP. ([Tor does not yet natively support UDP.](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/7830))
- A magic way to let you connect to clear-net destinations using IPv6. (Tor does not yet natively support IPv6.)
- A magic way to route everything through Tor, [like if you were using a VPN](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6900).

Comment: Tor does support IPv6 for most things, more are coming.

Comment: Could you run SIP through the setup explained above? ie lets say you and your partner setup a hidden service each, and created an OnionCat tunnel between you, could you now run SIP server such as FreeSWITCH or Asterisk and a SIP client such as Jitsi or Linphone between them for voice and video? That would mean running SIP/SRTP/ZRTP through the tunnel.

Comment: Yes, you can run any service through it, as long as it supports IPv6 (which is almost any service as of today).